Some tags in “Top Questions” in “Network Profile” have different colors for their font
See my network profile for top questions:

See the bug, status-completed, and email tags. They have a weird blue color in their tags’ font and they don’t like the color of their tags’ font in Meta Stack Exchange here.
I’m not sure, but it may be related to the newest announcement for tag design: All tag labels suddenly appear in bold font

Update 2: This is what I looked at from my IPad’s screen now:

tags, design and fonts also have blue color in their fonts.

@Slate can you please explain why did you add the status completed tag? I checked now and nothing has changed. If by mistake, please remove the tag and hopefully a developer will fix it one day. Thanks.

The blue color is because you visited those links. That is different than how tags on main and meta sites work.

@Shadow That's my error. I saw it was in [status-planned] and couldn't reproduce it (and could not find an open ticket for it internally), so assumed it was done. I've put it into [status-review] to make sure a ticket exists for it on our side.

@Slate Sorry to disturb you, should this question should be tagged [tag:status-completed] now? The issue looks fixed on my side.

@user1176409 Yes, thank you

I cannot make sure, but from my devices, no tags with blue color fonts were shown, maybe it’s status-completed!
Note: From this @Glorfindel comment on one of my deleted question, he said that:

There was no separate colouring for moderator-only and/or required tags on that page before: https://web.archive.org/web/20240303024633/https://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel

A screenshot from my IPad:



